# Display json data in table format in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following json which is a response from ajax call.

```
[  
   {  
      "Key1":"value1",
      "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"subvalue",
         "subkey2":"subvalue2"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Key1":"value1",
      "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"subvalue3",
         "subkey2":"subvalue4"
      }
   }
]
```

I have to display values of key 2 in html table.

```
subkey1         subkey2 
---------       ---------
subvalue1       subvalue2
subvalue3       subvalue4
```

Please note that number of columns are also dynamic.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? where you're facing problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys from first object with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to set the header. Then loop through the array with [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to set the table body.

Try the following way:

```js
var arrData = [  
   {  
      "Key1":"value1",
      "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"subvalue1",
         "subkey2":"subvalue2"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Key1":"value1",
      "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"subvalue3",
         "subkey2":"subvalue4"
      }
   }
]
var col = Object.keys(arrData[0].key2);
$('table').append('<thead><tr><th>' +col[0]+'</th><th>' +col[1]+'</th></tr></thead>');
$(arrData).each(function(i,v){
  $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>' +v.key2.subkey1+'</td><td>' +v.key2.subkey2+'</td>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @user2682527, if the answer solves  your problem then you can accept the answer by click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in......

Answer (score 0):

```
      var response = [  
           {  
              "Key1":"value1",
              "key2":{  
                 "subkey1":"subvalue",
                 "subkey2":"subvalue2"
              }
           },
           {  
              "Key1":"value1",
              "key2":{  
                 "subkey1":"subvalue3",
                 "subkey2":"subvalue4"
              }
           }
        ];

    var columns = [];

    if(response.length >0) {
         var item = response[0];
         columns = Object.keys(item['key2']);
    }

    var htmlStr = '<table><tr>';

    columns.map(function(col){
      htmlStr += '<th>'+col+'</th>'; 
    });

    htmlStr += '</tr>';



    response.map(function(item){
      htmlStr += '<tr>';
      columns.map(function(colName){
         htmlStr += '<td>' + item.key2[colName]+'</td>';
      });
      htmlStr += '</tr>';
    });

    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = htmlStr + '</table>';
```